# Cannot add ANY new ppa on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, ppa

this is an example:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa   
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpEVJtjw/secring.gpg' created  
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpEVJtjw/pubring.gpg' created  
gpg: requesting key 1378B444 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com  
gpg: /tmp/tmpEVJtjw/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created  
gpg: key 1378B444: public key "Launchpad PPA for LibreOffice Packaging" imported  
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found  
gpg: Total number processed: 1  
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)  
OK
```

The problem is: when i try to install LibreOffice it says:

```
$ apt-get install LibreOffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package LibreOffice
```

I have the same problem with almost every apps!! how can i fix this? 
Many Thx

Comment: What's your problem? The example you gave successfully added the ppa. It clearly says `OK` at the end.

Comment: Thxx 4 your answer, the problem is:
When i try to install LibreOffice it says :

apt-get install LibreOffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package LibreOffice

Comment: Please, edit your answer if you want to add more information.

Comment: How can i do so? :D

Comment: The package name is `libreoffice`, not `LibreOffice`. If you're not comfortable with the command line, remember that you can always use the Software Center ;-)

Comment: thx , but i can not fin libreoffice in th software center :D this a huge bizzar problem!

Comment: apt-get install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libreoffice is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package libreoffice has no installation candidate

Comment: don't forget the update command!

Answer (score 2):

The ppa from your example was successfully added. If you want to install Libre Office it's:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

When you install packages using the command line, you have to make sure you got the right package name. Tab-completion can help you with that. You can also use the Ubuntu Software Center where you can search.

Keep in mind that after you add a ppa you always have to update package source. Otherwise the packages aren't available. You can do this in the Software Center or by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Detailed instructions here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice

Comment: To be clear: the update command (that's the second command in the answer) should be run _first_ :)

Comment: Thank u all 4 your answers! 
the problem is not there, let s take another example: install Nitro (just to show u that i have a problem with all apps!)

add-apt-repository ppa:cooperjona/nitrotasks
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpsbo1yZ/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpsbo1yZ/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 2AE51AB5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpsbo1yZ/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 2AE51AB5: public key "Launchpad PPA for consindo" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

apt-get update

Comment: You can see [here](https://launchpad.net/~cooperjona/+archive/nitrotasks) that the package name seems to be `nitrotasks`. You always have the possibility to visit the ppa's webpage and see what packages are in there.

Comment: apt-get update
rr http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages 404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

Comment: As you can also see on that page, the ppa only has packages for Oneiric, Precise and Quantal. If you have 10.04 it would be "Lucid" so the package is not available for you in that ppa.

Comment: apt-get install nitrotasks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package nitrotasks

Comment: Oki thx anyway for your time :D gonna format my PC to solve it th old way :D have fun ;)